# VS2010, SP2010: NuGet package not being added to web.config

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, sharepoint-2010

This is my first Visual Studio 2010 / SharePoint 2010 Visual Web Part, and my first use of NuGet, so forgive my blinding ignorance. fwiw, this is for SP2010. I'm asking here instead of at sharepoint.stackexchange because I suspect it's more a VS question.

In VS2010, I have a SP2010 Visual Web Part project. It debugs clean and shows a basic "Hello World!" as desired. Looking at VisualWebPart1UserControl.ascx.cs, I have

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;

namespace VisualWebPartProject1.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPSite.UsageInfo usage = site.Usage;
            foo.Text = "Hello World!";
        }
    }
}
```

So far so good. Now what I really want to do on this page will involve some ugly date/time work, so I google, and discover a NuGet package, "TimePeriodLibrary.NET". I get NuGet config'd to work with VS2010, and I add the package to my project. I see the package refeerences added in References, great.

Problem comes when I try this:

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Itenso.TimePeriod;

namespace VisualWebPartProject1.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class VisualWebPart1UserControl : UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SPSite site = SPContext.Current.Site;
            SPSite.UsageInfo usage = site.Usage;

              TimeRange timeRange1 = new TimeRange(
              new DateTime(2011, 2, 22, 14, 0, 0),
              new DateTime(2011, 2, 22, 18, 0, 0));
              foo.Text = "TimeRange1: " + timeRange1;
        }
    }
}
```

It looks okay, but when I debug, I get:

```
"Could not load file or assembly 'Itenso.TimePeriod, Version=1.4.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d7f23b760ed5c748' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.":"Itenso.TimePeriod, Version=1.4.11.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d7f23b760ed5c748"
```

Being my first use of NuGet (amongst other firsts as you can tell), I was under the impression that it would modify web.config and basically 'make it work'. I've tried in desperation to even manually drag the needed .DLLs into the /BIN folder for the web application, but even that didn't work.

I'll admit it, I'm stumped. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions, but I did get it to work. 
http://jussionsharepoint.com/index.php/2012/02/08/using-global-assembly-cache-tool-gacutil-exe-effectively/
I located the .dll, and used **gacutil.exe /i** to install it to the GAC. Thereafter, everything worked as desired. I can't say authoratatively that this is the "right" way to get the desired results, but it appears to be so. I'm open to any wisdom the community wishes to pass along, should this not be the best way of getting it to work.

Answer (score 0):

You should right click the reference, select properties, and set the build operation to "Copy to local" (or something like this)

As a sidenote, the nuget manager just performs the operations inside the packages so almost certainly it's not the manager's fault when something goes wrong.

Comment: I looked and "Copy Local" was already set to "True". Just to see if it mattered, I flipped it to "False" and tried Debug again. No difference. Argh.

Comment: Seeing as the library doesn't have any dependencies, make sure it's added in the /bin/ folder upon build, and if the problem still persists try to copy the actual .dll from the /packages/ folder (solution root/packages/ThePackage/[...]) . If STILL the problem persists remove any references to it in the web.config . And if yet still the problem persists download the dll and paste it manually to the bin folder. That should cover all cases!

Comment: Tried that, too. No luck. Grabbed all the DLLs associated with the project, tossed 'em into the BIN folder.